# refrigertators that go into storage

Tags: storage, winterizing

just bought a new refrigerator.
it will be used in our SUMMER cottage.   We always winterized our old refrig, by emptying it, cleaning it, unplugging it and propping the door open.   We were told we should consider a garage kit.  I question why, if we unplug it.   Are we potetentially damaging the compressor?  the lines?   Refrigerator ideally will not run at all in the winter, in our unheated cottage, yet the walls are all insulated.

Jim

Comment: Jim, good question some will ask you to take the newcomers tour , it will give you an idea how the stack exchange works and we need more good questions like this !

Comment: "refrigertators" Those are the special tators that are always cold. :D (Love me a good typo!)

Comment: @FreeMan new term for potato salad ... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes seals can get funky not running for a long time, but that's no more a hazard for your new fridge than it was for your old one.

You certainly should not ned a "garage" or "cold running" kit for a fridge in a summer cottage that will be unplugged for the winter.

Check with the manufacturer for their storage recommendation when not using it, but that may well be impractical boilerplate (i.e. store above 45 degrees F or the like) rather than real insight to leaving it in a cold building. Given that they ship the things in winter in unheated trucks, I doubt there's a real issue there. Perhaps you'll get a company willing to say that...

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a great job!
With the system clean and open no bad bugs can grow.

Second, with the system turned off, if there is a leak, there will be much less pressure on the lines.

Last some might say that on a motor not regularly run, there will be no oil, so when it starts there will be massive metal on metal contact. Well not with hermetic compressors, like those in fridges.  In those, all the oil settles back in the compressor!

Standing a fridge up for 24 hours is required by some manufacturers to make sure the oil has time to make it back to the compressor.

You are doing everything right for a long life of your new fridge.